# Why is xcodebuild not building dependencies when testing?

Tags: target, xcodebuild

When I run `xcodebuild`, it crashes. It seems that it is not compiling the test target's dependency, which is the main app. The test target is called `NiknikTests`, while the app's target is called `WTATest3`.

```
Ld build/UninstalledProducts/NiknikTests.xctest/NiknikTests normal i386
    cd "/Users/ethen/.jenkins/workspace/Build NikNik"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/ethen/Desktop/sbt/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -L/Users/ethen/.jenkins/workspace/Build\ NikNik/build/Release-iphonesimulator -L/Users/ethen/.jenkins/workspace/Build\ NikNik/NiknikTests/TestLibraries/include/lib -F/Users/ethen/.jenkins/workspace/Build\ NikNik/build/Release-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/ethen/.jenkins/workspace/Build\ NikNik/build/NikNik.build/Release-iphonesimulator/NiknikTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/NiknikTests.LinkFileList -bundle_loader /Users/ethen/.jenkins/workspace/Build\ NikNik/build/Release-iphonesimulator/Niknik.app/Niknik -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -force_load /Users/ethen/.jenkins/workspace/Build\ NikNik/NiknikTests/TestLibraries/include/lib/libOCMock.a -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/ethen/.jenkins/workspace/Build\ NikNik/build/NikNik.build/Release-iphonesimulator/NiknikTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/NiknikTests_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/ethen/.jenkins/workspace/Build\ NikNik/build/UninstalledProducts/NiknikTests.xctest/NiknikTests
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NNBoundaryLineModel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in NNBoundaryLineModelTests.o
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NNBoundaryLineModelTests)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NNConstant", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in NNConstantTests.o
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NNConstantTests)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NNPlayerModel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in NNPlayerModelTests.o
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NNPlayerModelTests)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is my `xcodebuild` command:

```
xcodebuild \
-target NiknikTests \
-arch i386 \
-configuration “Debug” \
-sdk iphonesimulator \
TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY="2" \
ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO \
clean install
```

When I run the tests from inside of Xcode, it works just fine.

EDIT: This is showing the target dependency of `NiknikTests`.

[image]

Why is it not building the target dependency?

Comment: Which project are those classes included in?  The WTATest3?

Comment: @borrrden NNConstant, NNPlayerModel, and NNBoundaryLineModel are all from WTATest3, but their test case counterparts are from NiknikTests.

Answer (score 1):

I looks like it is not building the target dependency because of some issues with arch i386. In order to fix this I have two suggestions, 1) Delete the two arch statements from the xcodebuild command:

```
xcodebuild \
-target NiknikTests \
-configuration “Debug” \
-sdk iphonesimulator \
TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY="2" \
clean install
```

It should automatically choose the correct architecture for the program. However, if that does not work, 2) Try replacing "-arch i386 \" with "ARCHS=i386 \" IE

```
xcodebuild \
-target NiknikTests \
ARCHS=i386 \
-configuration “Debug” \
-sdk iphonesimulator \
TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY="2" \
ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO \
clean install
```

Comment: I tried both, and they didn't change anything, except that it referenced the architecture as `x86_64` instead of `i386`.

Comment: In your xcode project, under build settings what are the valid architectures?

Comment: `arm64 armv7 armv7s`. I'm guessing I need to add `i386`?

Comment: I added `i386` and tried all three configurations, but I'm still getting that error.

Comment: Now that you have added i386, try replacing "-arch i386 \" with  "CURRENT_ARCH=i386 \" and "ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO \" with  "ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES \"

Comment: It seems to be working now, possibly. It's giving me errors about problems in the code (which is further then it has gotten before), and I'm going to fix those errors and see if then the build passes.

Comment: Screw it, I'm awarding the bounty. It seems likely that your answer will fix it, and I have an hour of grace period left.

Comment: So I did what you said, and fixed the warnings. Now I get this error :`Check dependencies
No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=arm64 armv7 armv7s i386).` right when it starts the building (after the clean). Do I need to add `x86_64` to the list of valid architectures?

Comment: Yes, definitely add x86_64 and I'm pretty sure that will fix the errors. Now if that doesn't work, I'm just throwing suggestions out there: 1) try still using "CURRENT_ARCH=i386 \" and leaving "ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO \" alone. 2) Switch "CURRENT_ARCH=i386 \" to "ARCHS="arm64 armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64" and still switch "ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO \" with "ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES \".

Comment: adding `x86_64` just led back to the original error. Same thing with 1). 2) gave a different crash, which might be fore some syntax reason? Here's the full crash: https://gist.github.com/EthenAWilson/6b4e191ebf854ce2881c Also, at this point it might be relative that I am doing this over a local instance Jenkins, not at the command line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58905/discussion-between-ethen-a-wilson-and-user3817808).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try turning on build implicit dependencies under your build scheme ?

I had similar issues with Cocoapods and running unit tests

[image: Under build target -> edit scheme]